# Find neighborhood for torch tensor

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to implement a Self-Organizing Map where for a given input sample, the best matching unit/winning unit is chosen based on (say) L2-norm distance between the SOM and the input. The winning unit/BMU (som[x, y]) has the smallest L2 distance from the given input (z):

```
# Input batch: batch-size = 512, input-dim = 84-
z = torch.randn(512, 84)

# SOM shape: (height, width, input-dim)-
som = torch.randn(40, 40, 84)

print(f"BMU row, col shapes; row = {row.shape} & col = {col.shape}")
# BMU row, col shapes; row = torch.Size([512]) & col = torch.Size([512])
```

For clarity, for the first input sample in the batch "z[0]", the winning unit is "som[row[0], col[0]]"-

```
z[0].shape, som[row[0], col[0]].shape
# (torch.Size([84]), torch.Size([84]))
```

`torch.norm((z[0] - som[row[0], col[0]]))` is the smallest L2 distance between z[0] and all other som units except row[0] and col[0].

```
# Define initial neighborhood radius and learning rate-
neighb_rad = torch.tensor(2.0)
lr = 0.5

# To update weights for the first input "z[0]" and its corresponding BMU "som[row[0], col[0]]"-
for r in range(som.shape[0]):
    for c in range(som.shape[1]):
        neigh_dist = torch.exp(-torch.norm(input = (som[r, c] - som[row[0], col[0]])) / (2.0 * torch.pow(neighb_rad, 2)))
        som[r, c] = som[r, c] + (lr * neigh_dist * (z[0] - som[r, c]))
```

How can I implement the code for:

1. updating weights for all units around each BMU without the 2 for loops (and)
2. do it for all of the inputs "z" (here, z has 512 samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always consider the two spatial dimensions of `som` as a single flattened dimension. Considering your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78126805/6331369), it is preferable to work with `dist_l2.argmin(1)` (flattened indices) rather than `row` and `col` (unraveled indices). Let's write the intermediate tensors:

```
# expand batch-wise to (512, 1600, 84)
_som = som.view(1,-1,z.size(-1)).expand(len(z),-1,-1)

# expand z on dim=1 to match som
_z = z[:,None].expand(-1,40*40,-1)

# L2((512, 1600, 84), (512, 1, 84)) = (512, 1600, 1)
dist_l2 = torch.cdist(_som, z[:,None])[:,:,0]

# indices, shape reduced to (512,)
arg = dist_l2.argmin(1)
```

That way you can get all `som[row[i], col[i]]` just with `_som[range(len(arg)),arg]`. In vectorized form, you compute all iterations of the loop by introducing an extra dimension (of size `40*40`). Additionally we expand a singleton on `dim=1`:

```
som_arg = _som[range(len(arg)),arg][:,None]
```

So the L2 distance between `som[r, c]` and `som[row[i], col[i]])` corresponds to `torch.cdist(_som, som_arg)`:

```
# shape (512, 1600, 84) x (512, 1, 84) -> (512, 1600, 1)
l2_dist = torch.cdist(_som, som_arg)

# shape (512, 1600, 1)
neigh_dist = torch.exp(-l2_dist) / (2.0 * torch.pow(neighb_rad, 2))

# shape (512, 1600, 84) accumulated batch-wise -> (1600, 84)
out = (lr * neigh_dist * (_z - _som)).sum(0)
```

Finally, you can reshape to the desired squared form: `out.view(40,40,-1)`.